# What to do about areca palm stems and leaves to get healthy again

Tags: diseases, areca-palm

As you can see in the photo, the stems do not seem healthy. There's also another problem which causes the leaves to turn brown and curly. It is next to the window with direct sunlight, I water it once a week. The flat has floor heating.

[image]
[image]